# Hightchart to display user online time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have recently been working with the highchart api and i need to make a chart to display user online and offline time.

For example: I have 10 user with different name, and online time is:

- User 1: [8h30 -> 9h:00], [12h10 -> 12:20], [14h:00 -> 16h:00], [20:00 -> 22:20]
- User 2: [6h00 -> 7h:00], [11h10 -> 11:30], [12h:00 -> 12h:40]
- User 3: [9h30 -> 10h:00], [12h00 -> 12:10], [14h:30 -> 15h:40], [18:00 -> 19:20], [20:00 -> 23:20]
  ...

Time is unix timestamp. Something like this picture:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8743109/demo.png

if anyone has any ideas that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps should be multiplied by 1000, to have correct figure of timestamps (javascript). The next step is using columnrange chart like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: Thank for your answer Sebastian. Could i put multiple range on 1 series? Because 1 user online many time in a day, sometime they online (which will have a range), sometime they offline (which will not have a range), so they will have many range...

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by multiple range, have you a mockup?